# Why is this a memory copying error - Insure++ false positive?

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-management

I've been trying run [Insure++](http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/products/insure.jsp?itemId=63) with some scientific code and it reports many errors, although to be fair it officially does not support K&R C and I don't know what having a lot of K&R functions has done to its evaluation process. The C and C++ code it is testing is being run in a DLL invoked from a WPF application.

One error report that puzzles me is the following, which I'm confident is safe code but am trying to work out why it thinks is an error (it does work). I'd be interested if anyone has an insight into why this might be an error condition.

```
[MacImagePlot.c:984] **READ_OVERFLOW**
SetCursorQD(*GetCursorQD(watchCursor));

Reading overflows memory: GetCursorQD(watchCursor)

bbbbb
| 4 | 4 |
    rrrrr

Reading (r) : 0x5639d164 thru 0x5639d167 (4 bytes)
From block (b) : 0x5639d160 thru 0x5639d163 (4 bytes)
gWatchCursor, declared at WPFMacGraphics.cpp, 418
```

for some very simple code.

```
    typedef int Cursor;
    typedef Cursor* CursPtr;
    typedef CursPtr* CursHandle;
    CursHandle GetCursorQD (short cursorID);
    void SetCursorQD (const Cursor *crsr);
    enum {
    ....
     watchCursor =  4 
    };


    // file globals
    Cursor gWatchCursor=watchCursor;
    CursPtr gWatchCursorPtr = &gWatchCursor;

    CursHandle GetCursorQD (short cursorID)
    {
      if (cursorID==watchCursor)  // this is actually the only case ever called
        return &gWatchCursorPtr;
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you break up line 984 into three lines?  `CursHandle handle = GetCursorQD(watchCursor); CursPtr ptr = *handle; SetCursorQD(ptr);`  Then, on which line does the error occur?

Comment: Good question, `CursPtr ptr = *handle;
  Reading overflows memory: handle
          bbbbb
          | 4 | 4 |
              rrrrr
   Reading    (r) : 0x5ee64724 thru 0x5ee64727 (4 bytes)
   From block (b) : 0x5ee64720 thru 0x5ee64723 (4 bytes)`

Comment: It also reports an overflow if I write `const Cursor* ptr = *handle;` which makes me think it is even more likely to be false positive.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar at all with the tools you're talking about, but have you verified that your `GetCursorQD` function is returning the pointer you expect and not `NULL`/`0`?

Perhaps something wonky happened with your enum definition for `watchCursor` (such as it being declared differently elsewhere, or it picking up a local variable instead of the enum).

Comment: It's a good question but yes I'm absolutely certain - I've tested it with additional assertions in place to guarantee that and the code is actually working.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say it but I suspect your problem is going to be the lack of some arcane function modifiers needed to ensure that data on the stack isn't getting munged when crossing the DLL boundary.  I'd suggest writing a simple app that replicates the code but does it all in one module and see if Insure++ still detects an error.  If it doesn't, get ready to wade through __declspec documentation.

Comment: I'm sure there is a long and painful story behind your thinking ;-)  I already wrote a simple pure Win32 GUI that invokes the DLL with some canned scenarios, for other debugging, and I'll consider merging them as you suggest.

Comment: I just realised that the code which is generating the report IS within the same DLL as the functions it is invoking, so your interesting suggestion doesn't help here. I've written it off as a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the following line is the Problem:

```
  if (cursorID==watchCursor)
```

- `cursorID` is  defined as `short` (usually 2 Bytes)
- `watchCursor` is part of a enum and thus of type `int` (4 Bytes on a 32Bit OS)

This actually is not a problem. The compiler will cast one of both parameters correctly, as far as the enum value will not exceed a 2 Byte range.

By my experience all static (as well as runtime-) code analysis tools  report many false positives (i tried some of them). They of course help, but it takes quite a while to assert false positives from real bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Like Soapbox, I am not familiar with `Insure++`.

But looking at the code, it is admittedly a bit confusing...so

That typedef makes CursHandle effectively a pointer to pointer to int...

- CursHandle is a pointer of type CursPtr
- CursPtr is a pointer of type Cursor
- Cursor is typedef'd to type int

yet in the GetCursorQD, you are using a 'double address of' int? The reason I say 'double address' is the function is returning a *address* of `gWatchCursorPtr` *(**`&gWatchCursorPtr`**)* of type `CursHandle`, which in turn is a global variable which is a *address* of gWatchCursor *(**`&gWatchCursor`**)* which is of type `Cursor`.

Your definition of the return type for the function does not match up with the global variable name's *typeof* despite the typedef's...that's what my thinking is...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Blame Apple!

The typedefs and signatures are all standard Quickdraw (original Mac API) and I'm porting legacy code which for various reasons I need to leave as close to the original as possible. This particular line of code is repeated dozens of times.

Note that in the line of code that Insure++ complains about,  
`SetCursorQD( *GetCursorQD(watchCursor) );`  
the CursHandle returned is dereferenced with a leading * thus converting it back to a CursPtr so it does satisfy the Cursor* parameter type of SetCursorQD.

Thanks for taking the time to look.

Comment: @Andy: No problem...huh...Apple are full of surprises...never knew I was deciphering Apple's code..Learnt something new there eh? :D